# Not able to perform SFTP to another target server with same public key

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, sftp, key-authentication

I am trying to test the sftp connection to two target linux servers from the same USS source server. I had generated the public/private key pair in the source side and copied the public key to one target server and the sftp connection is successful, i.e I am able to login without password prompting.

But when I copied the same public key to the second target server, the key gets copied, yet it prompts for the password when I try to ssh. I checked all the permissions and authorities. They are all same as the first target system where sftp happened successfully.

I checked the known hosts file also in the source server, it has the required details about both target systems.

Can any one please hint where its going wrong?

This is the ls -la output for target server where sftp is successful.

[Target1sshid@TargetServer1 .ssh]$ ls -la

total 36

drwx------.  3 Target1sshid    EAB   164   Jun 21  2023 .

drwxr-x---. 13 Target1sshid    root 8192   Apr 11  2023 ..

-rw-------.  1 Target1sshid    EAB   393   Mar 21 12:41 authorized_keys

-rw-------.  1 root            root 1132   Feb 22  2023 authorized_keys_22

-rw-------.  1 root            root 1132   Feb  8  2023 authorized_keys_backup

-rw-------.  1 Target1sshid    EAB   394   Apr 12  2023 authorized_keys_bk

-rw-------.  1 Target1sshid    EAB  1679   Feb  7  2023 id_rsa

-rw-------.  1 Target1sshid    ias   399   Feb  8  2023 id_rsa.pub

drwx------.  2 Target1sshid    ias     6   Feb  6  2023 known_hosts.d

This is the ls -la output for target server where sftp failed

total 64

drwx------   2  Target2sshid  F9EDSECO    8192 Mar 21 18:36 .

drwxrwxrwx  12  104019        F9EDSECO    8192 Mar 23 05:27 ..

-rw-------   1  Target2sshid  F9EDSECO     393 Mar 21 14:43 authorized_keys

-rw-r--r--   1  Target2sshid  F9EDSECO     183 Mar 21 18:36 known_hosts

Thanks

Comment: Post verbose output (`-vvv`) from both.

Comment: Sounds like different configs - this is usually in /etc/ssh/sshd_config - check what the differences are here.

Comment: Please run `ls -la` on the ".ssh" directory of the remote server where the key isn't working, then [edit] your question to include the `ls` output. Also run ssh with the "-vvv" option while trying to connect to this server, then include the output in your question.

Comment: I edited my question to include the ls -la output. Please suggest.